# calling two functions in a single file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a utlityfunctions.js file,

where I have written two functions functionA and functionB.

```
exports.functionA = function(length)
{ 
  //do something
}
```

Now, in my functionB , I want to call functionA like this:

```
exports.functionB = function(length)
{
  functionA(1); 

}
```

But I am getting a runtime error "functionA not defined in functionB".

Is it possible to call functionA from functionB?

Comment: do you use functionA in other file too?

Comment: @Muhammad Ali ,yes the functionA is being used functions in other files also

Comment: `exports.functionA(1);`. Or just declare the function in the module scope and export it with `exports.functionA = functionA;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
exports.functionB = function(length) {
  this.functionA(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, do something like this.

```
var functionA = function(length) {
  // do something
}, functionB = function(length) {
  functionA(1);
}

module.exports = {functionA: functionA, functionB: functionB};
```

Now you can call each from outside using `require('utilityfunctions').functionA` or `require('utilityfunctions').functionB` and call each from inside.